# find delete shows "No such file or directory"

Tags: find, wildcards

I just run a command to "find and delete files & folder older than 100 days" on a folder, and got the following:

```
$ find . * -mtime +100 -delete
find: May_01_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_02_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_03_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_04_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_05_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_06_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_07_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_08_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_09_2015: No such file or directory
find: May_10_2015: No such file or directory
```

The folder names are correct (they should be deleted), but why is it complaining that it could not find those folders? (they were there)

---

Also, it's interesting, when I do:

```
$ find "$(pwd)" * -mtime +200 -print
```

I sometimes see the same file listed twice. I wonder if that's the reason. Why is it going through the same file twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `.*` with `find` and the space between `.` and `*` is often a mistake, since the `*` will expand to every entry in the current directory, and tell `find` to use that as a path to search.  That's also why your other `find` sometimes shows files twice.  If the `j$(pwd)` actually matches a file it will also be matched by `*`.

So your delete one will probably do better as:

```
find . -mtime +100 -delete
```

Though you might want to do it with `-print` to make sure you're getting what you want before deleting them of course.

Comment: Argh. I can't believe I missed this. Thanks @Eric !

Answer (score -1):

```
100 Days = 144,000 Minutes = 144000 Minutes

       -daystart
              Measure  times  (for  -amin,  -atime,  -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hours ago.  This option only affects
              tests which appear later on the command line.



 find "$(pwd)" -daystart -amin +144000 -exec ls -ltrio {} +
```

Comment: You do not explain why `atime` is relevant.  And your answer cannot be cross-checked 'cause you do not provide an example of how to create the files to reproduce your output.